# TFS Express 2012: Changed Windows server name, receiving error TF246017 and TF30040

Tags: tfs

I recently changed the hostname of the server that is hosting my Team Foundation Server Express 2012 instance from `synqueuemgmt` to `banedev`. The host OS is Windows Server 2012 Standard and is not a member of a domain. Now when I attempt to open the `Team Foundation Administration Console` I am receiving the following error:

> Team Foundation Error
>
> > TF246017: Team Foundation Server could not connect to the database. Verify that the server that is hosting the database is operational, and that the network problems are not blocking communication with the server.

I have attempted to run the following command from an elevated command prompt in order to point TFS back to the database with the new name:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Tools>TfsConfig.exe remapDBs /databaseName:banedev\SQLEXPRESS;Tfs_DefaultCollection /sqlInstances:banedev
```

However I am receiving the following error:

> TF30040: The database is not correctly configured. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator.

I am able to launch Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012 on the server and I can connect to the TFS Express SQLEXPRESS instance and I can successfully run queries against the databases that are contained under the instance. Can anyone please help me point my current installation of TFS express back to the database with the new server name? I'd really like to avoid uninstalling/reinstalling TFS Express since I have quite a few of my visual studio projects added to source control under the old server hostname.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to reconfigure TFS in order for it to use the new server name. From the command line call "tfsconfig.exe setup /uninstall:all"

Then open the admin console and run the "Configure Application Tier Only" wizard.

One compete your server will work. Changing the server name is the same as moving to a new server as far as TFS is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

I''ve ran in this same issue before. To resolve TF30040 1.) Exclude any files you may have in pending check-ins of team explorer in visual studio. 2.)Use an existing file or create a sample file that does not contain code dependencies and check it in. Once you check it in, that should clear the hang-up causing your TF30040 error.You should be able to go back and select your project in solution explorer, then get right click and select "Get Latest". Rebuild and clean the project, then your TF30040 error should go away. If the issue is still there, then you'll find doing "Get Latest" will trigger the error and you'll know whether this worked or not.